# WCF With Android- Binding result with labe or list view

Tags: android, asp.net, wcf, listview, adapter

1. I have created a WCF which take 2 parameter username and password.
2. I have created an android UI which take input username and password and on button click event it user name and password exist I have assigned a static value "Login successfully" to label.

I need guidance how can i bind the result set with label instead of passing static value to label.

public class JSONSampleAppActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

```
//Property declaration
Button btnLogin;
TextView lblStatus;
EditText txtUserName,txtPassword;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    btnLogin=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);
    btnLogin.setOnClickListener(this);

    lblStatus=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.lblStatus);

    txtUserName=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtUserName);
    txtPassword=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtPassword);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    switch(v.getId())
    {
        case R.id.btnLogin:
            String userName=txtUserName.getText().toString();
            String password=txtPassword.getText().toString();
            if(verifyLogin(userName,password))
            {

                lblStatus.setText("Login Successfully");
            }
            else
            {
                lblStatus.setText("Login Failed");
            }
            break;
    }
}

public static String convertStreamToString(InputStream is) 
{
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    String line = null;
    try {
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
    } 
    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
    finally {
        try {
            is.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return sb.toString();
}

public static boolean verifyLogin(String UserName,String Password)
{
    try
    {
        System.out.println("guru");
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient=new DefaultHttpClient();

        //Connect to the server
        HttpGet httpGet=new HttpGet("http://xxxx/Service1.svc/checkLogin?name="+UserName+"&pass="+Password);
        //Get the response
        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        InputStream stream=httpEntity.getContent();

        //Convert the stream to readable format
        String result= convertStreamToString(stream);

        if(result.charAt(1)=='1')
        {

            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        return false;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
To get the result set in label your code should look like this :

public static String verifyLogin(String UserName,String Password)
{
    try
    {
        System.out.println("guru");
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient=new DefaultHttpClient();

        //Connect to the server
        HttpGet httpGet=new HttpGet("http://xxxx/Service1.svc/checkLogin?name="+UserName+"&pass="+Password);
        //Get the response
        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        InputStream stream=httpEntity.getContent();

        //Convert the stream to readable format
        String result= convertStreamToString(stream);



    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return result;
}

call above method like this in onclick:

            String userName=txtUserName.getText().toString();
            String password=txtPassword.getText().toString();
            String res=verifyLogin(userName,password)
            lblStatus.setText(res);

whatever result is will be displayed in textview.
```

Comment: @ imran betara This wcf returns more than one row and each row has 2 columns. with above code it concatenates all the value of columns and bind it with one label. I want to bind column 1 value with label1 and column 2  value with label2, instead of concatenate. How can i achieve this task.

Comment: ok when result arrives at that time you can split the string which has two column values and store it in two variables. I mean to say after String res=verifyLogin(userName,password) you can split res and store in two different variable and display in two labels

Comment: this is my code now to bind result with label,   String res= verifyLogin(p);
             lblStatus.setText(res);
    break; when i replace (p) value with (username, password) it is giving error.

Comment: it is taking parameter from user